# Malloc string inside struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

My structure looks like this:

```
struct dir{
    char *path;
    int count;
    struct dir **subdir
};
struct dir *node;
```

I am doing the following to allocate memory to node:

```
name_to_copy = "root"
count_to_copy = 5;
node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
node->path = malloc(strlen(name_to_copy)+1);
memcpy(node->path, name_to_copy, strlen(name_to_copy)+1); //tried with strcpy as well
node->count = count_to_copy;
node->subdir = malloc(count_to_copy * sizeof(*dir));
```

When I print node->name, no matter what I try, it always prints 0x0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where did you define `node->name`?

Comment: try stepping thru this with a debugger and check at each step to see if your expectations match what's really happening.

Comment: Sorry, should be path, not name.

Comment: `sizeof(*dir)` This shouldn't compile to begin with. Please show actual code. Including the part that prints `node->path`.

Comment: What about just using [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can reproduce the problem. The behaviour you described should not occur with the code snippet you have provided so there must be something else wrong that you are not showing.

Comment: node = malloc(sizeof(*node)); you are allocating only size of 4 bytes (32 bit OS) to your struct. It should be node = malloc(sizeof(struct dir));

Comment: @Praveen That's not right. malloc of sizeof(*node) would allocate size of struct pointed by *node.

Comment: Also, this is just a better way of writing malloc. It does same thing as what you are saying

Comment: `node->name`? There is no such field. You seem to have posted fake code. Post a [mcve].

Comment: I am just making a guess with my crystal ball. As `node->subdir = malloc(count_to_copy * sizeof(struct dir));` is performed, `node->subdir->path` is not initialized to `null`. But later in the code (crystal ball...), the unitialized pointer `node->subdir[i].path` is dereferenced by using a function like `strcpy()`. It triggers an undefined behavior and the program crashes.